# Unsupported HTTP request method detected

Tags: c#, payment

right now I'm working on something payment to my website using `quickpay` and when I try to get to the page where I need to inform my payment to the side so for just this error:

```
Message Error Detected

An unrecoverable message error has been detected with the following information:

Unsupported HTTP request method detected - please use HTTP POST request

Please correct the problem and re-submit.
```

when I send it to send information over to their side do I like this:

**Html**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="protocol" runat="server" Value="" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="msgtype" runat="server"  />
<asp:HiddenField ID="merchant" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="language" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="ordernumber" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="amount" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="currency" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="continueurl" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="cancelurl" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="callbackurl" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="autocapture" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="md5check" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="ButtonBuyNow" OnClick="ButtonBuyNow_Click" runat="server" CssClass="btn pi-btn-base pi-btn-wide pi-uppercase pi-weight-700 pi-letter-spacing" />
```

When you click on the button so I do like this:

**c#**

```
protected void ButtonBuyNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(CheckBoxGodkend_Handelsbetingelser.Checked)
    {
        Response.Redirect("https://secure.quickpay.dk/form/");
    }
    else
    {
        LabelErrorCheck.Text = "- Husk at acceptere vores handelsbetingelser";
    }
}
```

into my hidden by continueurl and cancelurl and callbackurl I have written them like this:

```
string okpage_value = "/PayContinue";
            string errorPage_value = "/PayError";
            string resultpage_value = "/PayCallback";
```

Comment: You need to read quickpay payment implementation guide for supported/available HTTP request methods.

Comment: The accepted method is stated in the error message -- HTTP POST. You need to construct and send a POST request instead of a browser redirection.

Comment: @Avijit Where can I find it along the Danish ?, I could not find it at all.

Comment: @JesperPetersen Probably you need to translate it using Google translator from English to Danish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response.Redirect is a get request; you need to setup the submit button's PostBackURL property, which will not post back to your site, but to the Quickpay site.  See [this reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
<asp:button id="paybutton" runat="server"
  text="Pay with QuickPay" 
  postbackurl="..url.." >
</asp:button>
```

Looks like it should work: http://www.appetere.com/Blogs/SteveM/September-2010/Cross-site-posting-of-form-data-to-an-external-URL

Comment: Ohhh nice!! its work now, and now it coming and say "Missing/Invalid QuickpayId"